# Angular - Split Routes but main module doesnt accept

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an Angular app.

I've made good progress however now want to seperate code so its easier to maintain and read. To start with, i have my routes. I have the below in one file:

```
angular.module('theRoutes', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when("/",
    {
      templateUrl: "views/home.html"
    }
  )
  .when("/login",
    {
      templateUrl: "views/login.html"
    }
  )
  .when("/register",
    {
      templateUrl: "views/register.html"
    }
  );
})
```

And in my main app file where i have the main module I'm passing in as:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['theRoutes'])
...
```

However this doesnt work, any ideas?

Comment: I don't use angular's vanilla routing system but from what I see it looks alright. How is it not working? Are there any errors in the console? If you place an alert in the config do you see the alert when you refresh?

Comment: angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error…pis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.0-beta.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A3)

Comment: Be sure the file containing the route config is included before your main app file. Also be sure you've actually included the ngRoute file in your index. As of 1.2.x you have to do this manually.

Comment: So in my index i have 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular-route.js"></script>` and when you say file containg route confi before main app file what do you mean?

Comment: @userMod2 you should rather update your question than adding code and errors into the comments. By the way, I'd suggest you to have each module routes within the module. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y271

Comment: The file you use $routeProvider should be included before your app.js. That error is saying you're trying to include a module it can't find.

Comment: @userMod2 +1 for John Papa

Comment: Hmmm - i think i need to stop and restart my understanding of Angular. Thanks for the direction am reading that link now.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson - after a day after from the code what you said solved it. I forgot to mention that js file in my index.html. So thought that one app.js would link them all. Thanks